CKEditor 4 Image Upload & Drag and Drop Issue
I am integrating CKEditor 4 with my website and there I have an image upload option. The following is my configuration;
CKEDITOR.replace('newsBodytext', {
                    height: 200,
                    language: 'da',
                    format_tags: 'p;h2;h3;h4;h5;pre',
                    removeButtons: 'Underline,Strike,Styles,Anchor,About',
                    filebrowserUploadUrl: 'ck_upload.php',
                    filebrowserUploadMethod: 'form',
                    filebrowserUploadParams: function (file, xhr, formData) {
                        formData.append('CKEditorFuncNum', CKEDITOR.instances.newsBodytext.name);
                    }
                });

I wrote a PHP file "ck_upload.php" and the code is given below;
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['upload']['name']))
{
    $file = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'];
    $file_name = $_FILES['upload']['name'];
    $file_name_array = explode(".", $file_name);
    $extension = end($file_name_array);
    $new_image_name = rand() . '.' . $extension;
    $newPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/user_upload/';
    $allowed_extension = array("jpg", "gif", "png");
    if(in_array($extension, $allowed_extension))
    {
        move_uploaded_file($file, $newPath . $new_image_name);
        $function_number = $_GET['CKEditorFuncNum'];
        $url = '/user_upload/'. $new_image_name;
        $message = '';
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction($function_number, '$url', '$message');</script>";
    }
}
?>

The browser upload is working fine. But when adding "filebrowserUploadUrl", it breaks the default drag and drop functionality.

Here is the error on drag and drop;

Any solution for this issue. I need to work both of these solutions.

WHat behavior do you expect from this statement echo "<script ... in ck_upload.php?

While uploads the image to the server, it returns the URL @GetSet

Note that ck_upload.php&responseType=json is not the same as ck_upload.php?responseType=json. Where is this url being formed in your code? It is malformed.

Aside: Also note that if the responseType is expected to be json, then echo "<script ... will break that requirement.

yes, I am not sure where this &responseType=json appends on drag and drop. I only have the given code snippets @GetSet. Could you please help with any workaround?

Kindy hacky but affix a question mark as follows filebrowserUploadUrl: 'ck_upload.php?' and see what happens. But even if this works, still read the API itself to find the correct approach.

This is done, but it returns the URL like ck_upload.php?&responseType=json. server error.

Thats an improvement that it didnt discard the question mark. Where is ck_upload.php in the file path in relation to the code that calls it? Are they in the same or different folders?

No, it is a in a different path.
